# Draw an icon inside a canvas painted Oval/Circle in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to add a Icon into a drawn circle that is painted using Canvas, but I can't figure out how to do it correctly.

In this case I'm looking to adding the 'add' icon to the center of the drawn circle.

Notes: I'm trying to avoid in this case scenario using the Widget Stack().

**Circle Painter Code:**

```
class Circle extends CustomPainter {
  Circle();

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final _paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.green
      ..strokeWidth = 6
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    canvas.drawOval(
      Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height),
      _paint,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

Thank you in advance for any ideas you're able to give.

Comment: Can you include what type of `icon` you like to add? Does it custom PNG icon ?

Comment: Cyrus solved my Issue I just wanted to add the 'add' Flutter Icon "Icons.add" but I the use of Circle Avatar will simplify my objective in hand, thank you for replaying Yeasin Sheikh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add image like that

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
....
class CanvasPainter extends CustomPainter {
  List<ui.Image> items = new List<ui.Image>();

  void addItems(ui.Image item) {
    items.add(item);
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    for (ui.Image item in items) {
      canvas.drawImage(item,  Offset(50.0, 50.0),  Paint());
    }
  }
```

Or you just want to add image as circule form you can use circle avatar.

```
child: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        child: ClipRect(
          child: Image.network(
            'url-to-image',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      )
```

Comment: Thank You very much Cyrus, CircleAvatar will work fine I can't believe I didn't think of it I had little bit of a brain fart. I will be using CircleAvatar as it will keep my code much cleaner for the usage I need.